# Getting a NoMethodError after adding a new Controller to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, controllers

I am building an app that uses Devise as the authentication system. I have successfully overriden and extended the `Devise::RegistrationsController` with my own at `Campaigns::RegistrationsController` which works as intended. I've since tried to add a new controller in a similar fashion called Dashboard at `Campaigns::DashboardController` but have been getting a `NoMethodError in Campaigns::Dashboard#show` regarding `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`
 when I try to go to the url `/dashboard`.

It appears that the `Campaigns::DashboardController` is not inheriting the `Devise::RegistrationsController` like my custom `Campaigns::RegistrationsController`. I have no idea why that would be.

/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :campaigns, skip: [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords], controllers: {:omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'campaigns/registrations', dashboard: 'campaigns/dashboard'}
devise_scope :campaign do
  ...
  match '/account', to: 'campaigns/registrations#edit', via: 'get', as: :edit_campaign_registrations
  match '/dashboard', to: 'campaigns/dashboard#show', via: 'get', as: :show_dashboard
end
```

/campaigns/dashboard_controller.rb:

```
class Campaigns::DashboardController < Campaigns::RegistrationsController
  def show
    render :show
  end
end
```

The working /campaigns/registrations_controller.rb inheritance is:

```
class Campaigns::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...
end
```

I've also tried editing my /campaigns/dashboard_controller.rb to:

```
class Campaigns::DashboardController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def show
    render :show
  end
end
```

as the dashboard won't need the added methods in the new registration controller I added, but to no avail. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve it , i am stuck at the same place .

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out why the inheritance was not working. I actually just decided to not inherit from Devise. I found out that I didn't need to in order to get the functionality I needed.

I also had to remove the <%= devise_error_messages! %> and use an entirely different way of handling them. Basically, I set up a helper to handle the error messages and transfer them to flash messages, which I added to the top of my page. If you need help setting up the error message helper, I can provide that info as well.